# how to format mysql results to json php

Tags: php, json, arrays

mysql table

```
ID >> Name >> Salary
```

$row_set << database table information.

my problem is when i use

```
json_encode($row_set);
```

the output will be something like this:

```
[{"0":"1","ID":"1","1":"x","Name":"x","2":"12345","Salary":"12345"}]
```

i want the results to be something like this

```
[{"ID":"1","Name":"x","Salary":"12345"}]
```

how to do that ?

EDIT :: FULL CODE

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
     $row_set[] = $row;
  }
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

Comment: What function do you use to fetch rows from DB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume you are using `mysql_fetch_array` to get the row at the moment.

Try `mysql_fetch_array($resource, MYSQL_ASSOC)` (note the 2nd parameter!)

or `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.